# Pagination of the elastic buckets with size, from and order by a timestamp field

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to paginate the buckets with "size" and "from" ordered by the "Timestamp" field.
I have tried the bucket_sort but it did not work as it expects another sibling aggregation and cannot aggregate on the Timestamp field here. Elasticserch 6.7.2

My sample data is,

```
[{
    "Name": "Event A",
    "Timestamp": "2020-02-02T09:45:20.954Z"
},
{
    "Name": "Event B",
    "Timestamp": "2020-02-04T09:45:20.954Z"
},
{
    "Name": "Event C",
    "Timestamp": "2020-02-03T09:45:20.954Z"
},
{
    "Name": "Event A",
    "Timestamp": "2020-02-01T09:45:20.954Z"
},
{
    "Name": "Event D",
    "Timestamp": "2020-01-15T09:45:20.954Z"
}]
```

and current result is ordered by the doc_count but I want to order by date. My expected result is,

```
"buckets": [
        {
        "key": "Event B",
        "doc_count": 1
        }
        ,
        {
        "key": "Event C",
        "doc_count": 1
        }
        ,
        {
        "key": "Event A",
        "doc_count": 2
        }
        ,
        {
        "key": "Event D",
        "doc_count": 1
        }
  ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
I have tried the query to get the ordered buckets without "from" and result matched with the expected result,

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "eventNames": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Name",
                "size": 5,
                "order": {
                    "firstOccurredAggs": "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "firstOccurredAggs": {
                    "min": {
                        "field": "Timestamp"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But "from" cannot be used here with "terms" and "min".

Comment: Share the query you are using

Comment: Why can't you aggregate on the `Timestamp` field?

Comment: @PankhuriAgarwal query added

Comment: @jzzfs I want to paginate the event names based on their timestamp. it will introduce a lot of buckets and loops.

Comment: @ShivamPandey why would you worry about lots of buckets? You can always post-process the response and even limit the number of buckets in the first place.

You could also try using `top_hits` aggs within your `terms` agg. With that you can use `_source` to get only your desired fields and it also supports `from` and `size`.